# Render the html file in browser rather than forcing the download

Tags: java, html

I'm trying to render the html page in the browser rather than downloading the file. I have set the `content-disposition` to `inline; filename = 'file.html'`

IE renders the html file in the browser, but chrome and firefox are forcing it to download. I tried to load the .png file just to check if my code is forcing to download even the image, but image files are rendered in the browser itself. 
Is there anything I have to set in my code or should I load the html in an iframe so that the browser doesn't force the download.